# lualatex and lilypond/music notation

Tags: luatex, lilypond

Is there any easy way to embed musical notation into lualatex projects without too much hassle? (hopefully complete transparency)

I was thinking something like lilypond without having to do multiple compilations/etc.

I simply want to seemlessly add nice looking musical notation to some pre-existing lualatex code without too much trouble.

I've quickly did a search and it seems abc allows direct integration(used as a latex package) but does not have the look I'm after. lilypond requires external compilation and I have no ideas how it will interact with lualatex. Is there anything else out there, some lua like wrapper to directly integrate lilypond into lualatex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any lua like wrapper for lilypond, but I guess you
could use lilypond-book with lualatex, isn't it?

IIUC it should work if you invoke lilypond-book with the option
--latex-program=lualatex

```
lilypond-book --latex-program=lualatex yourfile.lytex
lualatex yourfile.tex
```

or something alike.

More info about lilypond-book in LilyPond Application Usage manual:
AU 3. Running lilypond-book
http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.15/Documentation/usage/lilypond_002dbook.html
and especially example  AU 3.1 An example of a musicological document ,
AU 3.2.1 LaTeX  and  AU 3.4 Invoking lilypond-book .